# Read only properties in Web API 2 with OData

Tags: odata, asp.net-web-api2

I have a class:

```
public class Person
{
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I can happily configure it up with OData:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>();
```

But how can I tell OData that I want `DateCreated` to be read only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If DateCreated is only useful on the server side, then you can configure that it is not exposed to the client side by adding an attribute:

```
[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.NotMappedAttribute]
public DateTime DateCreated{get;set;}
```

In the PeopleController, you need to set its value before store it to database or somewhere:

```
public class PeopleController
{
    public IHttpActionResult Post(Person person)
    {
        person.DateCreated=DateTime.Now;
        // Storing the person goes here
        return Created(person);
    }
}
```

Now it is not supported to just indicate that a property is ReadOnly.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm talking about a scenario where I want to expose the value to the client, but read only

Comment: Currently it is not supported. But on the server side, you can choose to ignore the property value.

Comment: Hi Tan, thank you - if you have a reference for that (or are you on team?) then you should put that as the answer so I can accept!